# Error listing information from an API (Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String')

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting information from a REST API, but when displaying the information I get the error:

> Error: Exception: Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'

This is my get method:

```
  Future<List<Requests>> searchRequests() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(BaseUrl.baseUrl + 'api/search'));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<Requests> list = parseRequests(response.body);
        return list;
      } else {
        throw Exception("Error");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
  }

  static List<Requests> parseRequests(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed
        .map<Requests>((json) => Requests.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
  }
```

and defined my model like this:

```
import 'package:flutter_gentelella/models/usuario.dart';

class Requests {
  final String id;
  final String data1;
  final String data2;
  final int data3;

  const Requests({
    required this.id,
    required this.data1,
    required this.data2,
    required this.data3,
  });

  factory Requests.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Solicitacoes(
        id: json['_id'],
        data1: json['data1'],
        data2: json['data2'],
        data3: json['user']['data3']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        '_id': id,
        'data1': data1,
        'data2': data2,
        'data3': data3,
      };
}
```

**At what point in the code do I convert to int?**

I'm trying to generate the order list on the screen but I get the error reported above. I appreciate if someone helps me analyze!

Comment: Print response.body to see the response.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the problem is with the field `data3`: it's the only thing I see in your code defined as an `int`, and the error is telling you that something was expected as `int` but it came up as `String`.

Something like this shouls work (just handle the case in which `data3` is not a number appropriately):

```
 factory Requests.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Solicitacoes(
        id: json['_id'],
        data1: json['data1'],
        data2: json['data2'],
        data3: int.tryParse(json['user']['data3']) ?? 'Not a number');
  }
```

Comment: I tried to do it the way you mentioned, but the error persists. When I leave for example just data3, which is an integer, it works. But if I add a "String" it gives an error.